# Debian Linux Raspbian- Raspberry Pi time offset is 65s ahead of UTC

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ntp

For some strange reason unknown to me, my RPi appears to have been set incorrectly to UTC +65s. The output I receive is the following:

```
sudo ntpd -gq
ntpd: time set -65.706156s
```

I have tried stopping and restarting ntp server (no effect).

When I check the sync servers using the following command, I do receive a ping back so it's not a case of the servers not responding, or a firewall issue:

```
grep -P "^server" /etc/ntp.conf
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst

ping -c 1 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
PING 0.debian.pool.ntp.org (193.1.219.116) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tbag.heanet.ie (193.1.219.116): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=18.8 ms

--- 0.debian.pool.ntp.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.818/18.818/18.818/0.000 ms
```

I'm at a loss as to how to correct this.

UPDATE:

Running the `ntpq -p` command yields the following info:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*adsl-172-10-0-1 117.70.*.110   4 u    2   64    7    0.617   -0.070   0.109
```

Is this the ntp server that I'm trying to sync to - because that IP belongs to CHINANET (I don't know how or why).

I also tried to manually set the RPi time, after stopping ntp service, setting the time correctly and restarting the service.

What I noticed was that the time was correctly set for a good 5 seconds, before reverting back to it's 65s offset. So it appears that this is the issue.

Comment: check logfiles.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: thats great, thanks for the advice. perhaps you could also help me in moving this to the correct place - can this be done easily or do I need to replicate the question and answer manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution as described in post 6 of the link:

http://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/13035-Raspberry-Pi-NTP-service-not-using-etc-ntp-conf/

Basically, connecting the RPi to the network, the DHCP server acts as the NTP server and creates a copy of the ntp.conf file in the location `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp`

This file overrides the default `/etc/ntp.conf` file, so deleting it and then stopping the ntp service, performing a resync, and then starting the service is the only way to resolve this.

The command for resync is:

```
sudo ntpdate -b pool.ntp.org
```

The original issue was that the ntp server was syncing with a CHINANET server and causing a 65s offset, which I suspect is down to a misconfigured DCHP/NTP server on our network.